# QR code inclusion in Mass-mailings

Tags: civimail

I wish to include a personalised QR-code in the Mass Mail for people in the Grace list, to facilitate their payment, which in Sweden can be done by the Swish function: use your phone, read/scan the QR code, key in your PIN, and the payment is done.

The problem I meet is to understand how I can invoke the result (a unique personalised QR png-file) of an API-request (to the Swish company) in the flow of text in the mass-mail message.

Has anybody done this before? Can php be invoked or Python?

Claes

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you would want to create a custom token. See https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokens/

So for the value of the token you would need to do the Swish api call and then use the result.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the function, unknown to me at preset, but it looks exciting! I will post back when I've tried.
Claes